# What projection to use with Mapbox base/reference layers?

Tags: web-mapping, coordinate-system, tilemill, mapbox

excuse me if this has been asked before, but I can not find answer after heavy googling.

What coordinate system/projection does shapefiles need to be in to be alligned correctly with mapbox reference layers?

[This](https://www.mapbox.com/help/projection-support/) page states that the only projection supported is web mercator. However, when I project my shapefile to web mercator in ArcMap, the shapefile is displayed over Africa? Am I simply missing false easting and northing values?

Anyway, [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1oAI.jpg) are examples of alignments with two different projections.

As displayed above I've convert my shapefiles into different projections, without managing to align them with the reference layer. Help please?

Comment: What tool/software are you using to transform your data's projection?

Comment: ArcMap's define projection.

Comment: You need to use the Project tool, not Define Projection. See answer to this question for details on why: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/108410/cannot-obtain-correct-area-values-with-correct-projections

Comment: I'm still trying to make the tool work properly, but I am certain that this is the solution. So, thank you very much Erica :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Layers with same coordinate system should align/overlap but do not?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20572/layers-with-same-coordinate-system-should-align-overlap-but-do-not)

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to re-project your shapefile in Arc Map (Tilemill will do it).
Instead, when you add your layer in Tilemill you have to select **Custom** for **SRS** and enter the complete datum of your shapefile.

[image]